# Dropbox API, How to see each team member's folder permissions?

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am new to using the Dropbox API and I want to access every team member's folder permissions and put it into a database, but I'm having trouble on where to find this information. I am able to access each member's folders and can see the name of every folder, but not the permissions of each folder that the user has. How can I do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
public MainPage()
{
     this.InitializeComponent();
     var task = Task.Run((Func<Task>)MainPage.Run);
     task.Wait();
}


static async Task Run()
{
      using (DropboxTeamClient DBTeamClient = new DropboxTeamClient("MY ACCESS KEY"))
      {
            //get all the dropbox members
            var members = await DBTeamClient.Team.MembersListAsync();
            //loop through all members ordered by email alphabetical
            foreach (var member in members.Members.OrderBy(a => a.Profile.Email))
            {
                 //get each user
                 var userClient = DBTeamClient.AsMember(member.Profile.TeamMemberId);
                 //get each user's file information
                 var list = await userClient.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty);
                 //loop through the list of file and show permissions on folders
                 foreach (var item in list.Entries.OrderBy(b => b.PathDisplay))
                 {
                     //only display folder information
                     if (item.IsFolder)
                     {
                         //find out the user's permissions to this folder here?
                         //then I will output user information and permissions to a db
                     }
                 }
            }
      }
}
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way? Any guidance is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/How-to-get-each-team-member-s-permissions-per-folder-using-NET/m-p/383460#M21340 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Greg's comment and post on Dropbox I was able to solve my problem. Here is his solution:

"When you list files and folders using FilesUserRoutes.ListFolderAsync like this, you're listing the contents of the member's Dropbox folder, which will include both shared folders (where they have some specific permission level) as well as their private folders (where they don't have a specific permission level, since it's just their folders). For shared folders, the returned FolderMetadata.SharingInfo will be set, but it doesn't contain information about that user's permission level in that folder. (By the way, make sure you implement ListFolderContinueAsync as well, to make sure you can retrieve all results, when using ListFolderAsync. Check out the ListFolderAsync documentation for more information.)

Instead, if you want to list the shared folders the user has access to, including their level of access in each one, you should use SharingUserRoutes.ListFoldersAsync. Likewise, make sure you implement SharingUserRoutes.ListFoldersContinueAsync too, as this interface is also paginated. Each returned SharedFolderMetadata will list the user's AccessType and Permissions.

Here's a little example:

```
var actionsToCheck = new Dropbox.Api.Sharing.FolderAction[] { Dropbox.Api.Sharing.FolderAction.EditContents.Instance, Dropbox.Api.Sharing.FolderAction.InviteEditor.Instance };
var list = await userClient.Sharing.ListFoldersAsync(actions: actionsToCheck);  // actions can optionally be supplied to check the permissions the user has for specific actions

foreach (var item in list.Entries)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.SharedFolderId);
    Console.WriteLine(item.PathLower);  // only set if the folder is mounted
    Console.WriteLine(item.AccessType);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Permissions);
}

// and so on, iterating over pages from userClient.Sharing.ListFoldersContinueAsync if list.Cursor is set
```

Hope this helps!"

I hope others find this as useful as I did.